# Gatsby - Open Graph and Twitter cards not working

Tags: html, reactjs, gatsby

I'm working on a website clone and I implemented the corresponding meta-tags using an [SEO component](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/add-seo-component/) but none of the social media sharing cards are working. Here's the `<head>` tag of my website:

```
<head>
   <meta charset="utf-8">
   <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge">
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
   <meta name="generator" content="Gatsby 2.26.1">
   <link as="script" rel="preload" href="/webpack-runtime-df072eede683f8962056.js">
   <link as="script" rel="preload" href="/framework-e2d419ac45d8ae41957a.js">
   <link as="script" rel="preload" href="/532a2f07-a2b9837034ae8adfec32.js">
   <link as="script" rel="preload" href="/app-157e8d102f227165e079.js">
   <link as="script" rel="preload" href="/styles-e9d24b1846c7d6eb9685.js">
   <link as="script" rel="preload" href="/1bfc9850-80572dcfa3a188680d98.js">
   <link as="script" rel="preload" href="/commons-6f2e27ca03a3d80d5bd3.js">
   <link as="script" rel="preload" href="/component---src-pages-index-tsx-c94d9cadb25e22723606.js">
   <link as="fetch" rel="preload" href="/page-data/index/page-data.json" crossorigin="anonymous">
   <link as="fetch" rel="preload" href="/page-data/sq/d/2052298874.json" crossorigin="anonymous">
   <link as="fetch" rel="preload" href="/page-data/sq/d/4230121995.json" crossorigin="anonymous">
   <link as="fetch" rel="preload" href="/page-data/app-data.json" crossorigin="anonymous">
   <title>Bootcamp de programación - Aprende programación y ciencia de datos | Bootcamp de programación - Aprende programación y ciencia de datos</title>
   <link rel="canonical" href="https://codingdojo-test.netlify.app/" data-react-helmet="true">
   <meta name="description" content="¿Interesado en comenzar una nueva carrera en tecnología? Aprende a programar en una de los mejores academias del mundo. Crea tu primer sitio web y aplicación en cuestión de semanas. Enseñamos Python, Java, .NET, iOS, Javascript y más. Opciones de aprendizaje en línea y becas disponibles. ¡Inscríbete hoy!" data-react-helmet="true">
   <meta name="keywords" content="Bootcamp,Aprende a programar,Python,Programación,Javascript,Blockchain,Django,Nodejs,cursos de programación" data-react-helmet="true">
   <meta property="og:title" content="Bootcamp de programación - Aprende programación y ciencia de datos" data-react-helmet="true">
   <meta property="og:url" content="https://codingdojo-test.netlify.app/" data-react-helmet="true">
   <meta property="og:description" content="¿Interesado en comenzar una nueva carrera en tecnología? Aprende a programar en una de los mejores academias del mundo. Crea tu primer sitio web y aplicación en cuestión de semanas. Enseñamos Python, Java, .NET, iOS, Javascript y más. Opciones de aprendizaje en línea y becas disponibles. ¡Inscríbete hoy!" data-react-helmet="true">
   <meta property="og:type" content="website" data-react-helmet="true">
   <meta name="twitter:creator" content="Coding Dojo Chile" data-react-helmet="true">
   <meta name="twitter:title" content="Bootcamp de programación - Aprende programación y ciencia de datos" data-react-helmet="true">
   <meta name="twitter:description" content="¿Interesado en comenzar una nueva carrera en tecnología? Aprende a programar en una de los mejores academias del mundo. Crea tu primer sitio web y aplicación en cuestión de semanas. Enseñamos Python, Java, .NET, iOS, Javascript y más. Opciones de aprendizaje en línea y becas disponibles. ¡Inscríbete hoy!" data-react-helmet="true">
   <meta name="twitter:card" content="summary" data-react-helmet="true">
</head>
```

Or, if you want to see it online: https://codingdojo-test.netlify.app/

Twitter card validator throws an error when trying to fetch the card and so does facebook. What am I missing?

EDIT: Here's my SEO component

```
import React from "react"

import { Helmet } from "react-helmet"

import { useLocation } from "@reach/router"
import { useStaticQuery, graphql } from "gatsby"

type SEOProps = {
  title?: string
  description?: string
  meta?: []
  image?: {
    src: string
    width: number
    height: number
  }
}

const SEO = ({ title, description, meta = [], image: metaImage }: SEOProps) => {
  const { pathname } = useLocation()
  const { site } = useStaticQuery(
    graphql`
      query {
        site {
          siteMetadata {
            title
            description
            author
            keywords
            siteUrl
          }
        }
      }
    `
  )
  const metaDescription = description || site.siteMetadata.description
  const image =
    metaImage && metaImage.src
      ? `${site.siteMetadata.siteUrl}${metaImage.src}`
      : null
  const canonical = pathname ? `${site.siteMetadata.siteUrl}${pathname}` : null
  return (
    <Helmet
      htmlAttributes={{
        lang: "es",
      }}
      title={title}
      titleTemplate={`%s | ${site.siteMetadata.title}`}
      link={
        canonical
          ? [
              {
                rel: "canonical",
                href: canonical,
              },
            ]
          : []
      }
      meta={[
        {
          name: `description`,
          content: metaDescription,
        },
        {
          name: "keywords",
          content: site.siteMetadata.keywords.join(","),
        },
        {
          property: `og:title`,
          content: title,
        },
        {
          property: "og:url",
          content: `${site.siteMetadata.siteUrl}${pathname}`,
        },
        {
          property: `og:description`,
          content: metaDescription,
        },
        {
          property: `og:type`,
          content: `website`,
        },
        {
          name: `twitter:creator`,
          content: site.siteMetadata.author,
        },
        {
          name: `twitter:title`,
          content: title,
        },
        {
          name: `twitter:description`,
          content: metaDescription,
        },
      ]
        .concat(
          metaImage
            ? [
                {
                  property: "og:image",
                  content: image,
                },
                {
                  property: "og:image:width",
                  content: metaImage.width,
                },
                {
                  property: "og:image:height",
                  content: metaImage.height,
                },
                {
                  name: "twitter:card",
                  content: "summary_large_image",
                },
              ]
            : [
                {
                  name: "twitter:card",
                  content: "summary",
                },
              ]
        )
        .concat(meta)}
    />
  )
}

export default SEO
```

Comment: Twitter, linkedin and co only read html and does not interpret your JS. You must server side rendering your page

Comment: Can you show your seo component?

Comment: @Yanis-git Gatsby uses pre-rendering, so the HTML is there to be crawled

Comment: @Akshay I edited, you can check it out

Comment: Just confirming, you are using `gatsby-plugin-react-helmet` in gatsby-config right?

Comment: No, I'm not. The page does not day that I should install it

Comment: Oh, I see, the HTML gets generated but without the plugin it will be dynamic, right? And that's why it's not working?

Comment: Yeah, hope you got it working

Answer (score 1):

I needed to install `gatsby-plugin-react-helmet` to pre-render the Helmet component. Seems weird that in another project I have the same thing but rendered correctly. I believe it is because this one has older versions of packages.